# Store large Image Files coded as base64 in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, image, spring-boot, gridfs

I use a spring boot application with mongoDB as storage and want to store large image-files coded as base64 strings. As i know, mongoDB can only store files up to 16MB so i have to use gridfs. In multiple pages and tutorials they store files but i never found an example for storing objects with gridfs.

Basic example:

```
public class Student {

private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String image;

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
public String getImage() {
    return image;
}
public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}
}
```

Do i have to store image-value seperately as an inputStream like mentioned here:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-mongodb-upload-file

Or are there other approaches?

Comment: MongoDB can store huge files (terabytes if need). You don't need to serialize your images to Base64 string since GridFS accepts raw files and stores in small parts named chunks. If you still need to store as Base64, you need to convert your Object to Stream and invoke appropiate method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can store meta data with gridfs

OR

if you want to store complete object then follow below steps:

1. store only file in gridfs it will return a refernceid
2. add referenced id to your object and store it into different document in mongoDB

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This worked for me. But how do i guarantee that files are not stored dublicated? Is it possible to distinct the results?

Comment: if this solution worked for you then please accept my answer and it will not store duplicate, for a single gridfs id document saved once